# Ignited/Laravel-pdf - White screen of death - Unable to generate PDFs

Tags: php, pdf, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

This is probably a really simple one, but I cannot get it working...

I would like to generate a PDF from a Blade View.

In order to do this, I have installed via composer:

```
    "ignited/laravel-pdf": "1.*",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "*",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "*"
```

I have set up my service providers and facades as follows:

```
    'Ignited\Pdf\PdfServiceProvider',
    'PDF'             => 'Ignited\Pdf\Facades\Pdf'
```

And I have published configuration settings and tried both configurations.

```
return array(
    # Uncomment for 32-bit systems
    'bin' => base_path() . '/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386'

    # Uncomment for 64-bit systems
    #'bin' => base_path() . '/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'

    # Add any global Wkhtmltopdf options here
    #'no-outline',
    #'margin-top'    => 0,
    #'margin-right'  => 0,
    #'margin-bottom' => 0,
    #'margin-left'   => 0,
);
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
public function getPDF($id)
{
    $pdf = PDF::make();
    $pdf->addPage('<html><head></head><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>');
    $pdf->send();
}
```

but when I visit that page, I just get a white screen.

Once I eventually have Hello World showing up, I would like to be able to pass a view to this to be rendered as a PDF.

My thoughts are that laravel-pdf  simply isn't doing anything as if I `dd('helloooo')` after `$pdf->send()`, I just get `string(8) "helloooo"` when I visit that page in the browser.

Any thoughts or am I being super dumb?

Comment: did you run *composer install* and *composer dump-autoload*? Also WSOD are commonly because of filesystem writing permission problems

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this in app/routes.php file ?

```
Route::get('pdfhello', function() {
    $pdf = PDF::make();
    $html = View::make('hello');
    $pdf->addPage($html);
    $pdf->send('hola.pdf');
});
```

IMPORTANT: It seems that the following line in app/view/hello.php throws the white screen of death.

<strike>@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);</strike>

Likely some CSS directives, and maybe some blade directives, cause the pdf file not to be created.